# JavaScript uk-modal-close and reload page

Tags: javascript

Hi i am using http://getuikit.com/docs/modal.html on my site,

my code as below

```
<a href="#my_modal" class="uk-button" data-uk-modal="">Click to open modal</a>
<div id="my_modal" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <a href="" class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>...body ...</p>
        <div  class="uk-modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="uk-button uk-modal-close" id="openmodal">Cancel</a> <!-- Just close the modal -->
           <!-- Call external link -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to refresh background when some one click Cancel, i am noob in js but done some research and found

```
location.reload(true);
```

this will help in reload page but don't know how can i use it, can any one help

Answer . add this in end of page

```
<script>
        $('.uk-modal').on({
            'hide.uk.modal': function(){
                location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](http://getuikit.com/docs/modal.html), you may use the `hide.uk.modal` event, which is trigged whenever the modal is closed. In the event handler, you can use the reload functionality. Include jQuery file as well.

```
$('.modalSelector').on({
    'hide.uk.modal': function(){
       location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi i am trying it but dont know if using it right or not can you please check http://jsfiddle.net/Wgrcy/9/ ....

Comment: i just add this in end of page and it worked ... <script>
        $('.uk-modal').on({
            'hide.uk.modal': function(){
                location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    </script>